# BeanMapping: Replace value in set within mapping expression?

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I have a string Set I'm mapping into a bean for a PDF form content extraction:

```
@Mapping(target = "targetFieldName", expression = "java(contentMapperService.convertStringToSet(pdfFieldsMap.get(\"PDF_field_name\")))")
```

Let's say the input String from the PDF field is "apple,banana"

If we find the value "apple", we want to replace it with "apples" before the set is mapped to the target.

Is this possible to do within an expression?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method with your specific logic and use it with the property qualifiedByName:

Cause you don't provide the mapper, take this as an example.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "targetFieldName", source = "pdfFieldName", qualifiedByName = "setTargetFieldName")
    Target toTarget(Source source);

    @Named("setTargetFieldName") 
    default String setTargetFieldName(String pdfFieldName){
        return pdfFieldName.replace("apple", "apples");
    }

}
```

- Official documentation: [adding-custom-methods](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#adding-custom-methods)
- Baeldung tutorial: [mapstruct-custom-mapper](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct-custom-mapper)